# Proof that $\lim _{x\to \infty }(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x)=1$ using the epsilon delta definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

Starting with,
$$|\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x-1|<\epsilon$$

So my initial attempt to this problem is to factor out the $x$ out:
$$|x||\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -x^2-\frac{1}{x}|<\epsilon$$

and then we can restrict $x>2$, such that $\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -x^2-\frac{1}{x}<\sqrt2-1-\frac{1}{2}$

so,
$$|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt2-1-\frac{1}{2}}$$

**However,** I just realized that my target was supposed to be $|x|>M$, not $|x|<M$, so I cannot proceed with the final inequality I found above. I tried factoring out $|1/x|$ for the initial step with the hope of getting to $|\frac{1}{x}|<M$, but I am stuck.

So how can I find the suitable $M$ needed for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x > 0$ to begin with. $\left|\sqrt{x^2+2x} - x-1\right|= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x} + x+1}< \dfrac{1}{x+1}< \epsilon$. Can you solve for $x$ in the last inequality and then find $M$ ?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. It would be $x>\epsilon-1$ and so we use $M=min\{0, \epsilon-1\}$, is that correct?

Comment: $x > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} - 1 \implies M = \text{max}\left(0,\dfrac{1}{\epsilon} - 1\right)$.

Comment: I see, sorry for the careless mistake, now I got it. Thanks a lot for the help!